# How to recalculate form array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want the user to update multiple rows at once so I created a form like this (I stripped out the HTML to show what I really mean):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {

    @{int i = 0; }
    @foreach(var row in Model) {
        @Html.TextBox("Customer["+ i +"].CustomerID")
        @Html.TextBox("Customer["+ i +"].Name")
    }

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

The output in HTML is (for 3 rows):

```
<input type="text" name="Customer[0].CustomerID" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[0].Name" />

<input type="text" name="Customer[1].CustomerID" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[1].Name" />

<input type="text" name="Customer[2].CustomerID" />
<input type="text" name="Customer[2].Name" />
```

When the user clicks the submit button, the data is sent to a Controller:

```
Public ActionResult EditCustomer(IEnumerable<Customer> Customer) {
}
```

Which gives me a nice IEnumerable with all the entered data and I can do whatever I want. It works as expected.

Now I'd like to take it one step further and allow the user to remove rows.

**This fails**

Because when I remove the second row, the array is no longer 'closed': it goes from Customer[0] to Customer[2] and ASP.NET MVC has problems with that.

So I think that can be solved with recalculating the indexes. But how do I do this in jQuery?

So that after the middle row has been deleted a function is run that updates `Customer[2].CustomerID` to `Customer[1].CustomerID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which illustrates a nice helper that you could use for achieving that instead of using magic strings.

Comment: Hmm, new problem. Primary keys are reset to zero (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330598/primary-key-set-to-zero-on-submit-of-ienumerablet)