# Primary key set to zero on submit of IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

So I created a variable length list using the code shown [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

When I submit the form, the primary keys are reset to 0. In the HTML form, they are not zero but the actual values. How do I fix this?

**The form**

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Kortingartikel")) { 

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Artikelid)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Artikelnaam)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Prijs)</td>

}
```

**The data**

According to Chrome, this data is sent to the server:

```
Kortingartikel.index:ad56efb0-ab7f-4b37-9d9b-712d7c3e3543
Kortingartikel[ad56efb0-ab7f-4b37-9d9b-712d7c3e3543].Artikelid:5
Kortingartikel[ad56efb0-ab7f-4b37-9d9b-712d7c3e3543].Artikelnaam:test artikel een
Kortingartikel[ad56efb0-ab7f-4b37-9d9b-712d7c3e3543].Prijs:10,00
Kortingartikel.index:b9624d8f-38e6-4092-ba1b-d004d0443a43
Kortingartikel[b9624d8f-38e6-4092-ba1b-d004d0443a43].Artikelid:6
Kortingartikel[b9624d8f-38e6-4092-ba1b-d004d0443a43].Artikelnaam:test artikel twee
Kortingartikel[b9624d8f-38e6-4092-ba1b-d004d0443a43].Prijs:5,00
```

**The Action**

The data is sent to the following action:

```
public ActionResult Kortingartikel(IEnumerable<Kortingartikel> Kortingartikel)
```

The 'Kortingartikel' parameter has the following values:

```
[0]Artikelnaam:test artikel een
   Prijs: 10
   Artikelid: 0
[1]Artikelnaam:test artikel twee
   Prijs: 5
   Artikelid: 0
```

**The property/field Artikelid**
Artikelid is generated from a linq-to-sql dbml file. Here is the (autogenerated) code:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="artikelid", Storage="_artikelid", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public long Artikelid
    {
        get
        {
            return this._artikelid;
        }
                    set
        {
            if ((this._artikelid != value))
            {
                this.OnArtikelidChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._artikelid = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Artikelid");
                this.OnArtikelidChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't really say without seeing more code.  What do the viewmodel and submitted model look like? What does your form look like?  Are you doing any special model binding?  At first, it sounds like a binding issue where the primary key (I'm assuming an int) isn't being sent from the view properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the `Artikelid` on your `Kortingartikel` view model either doesn't have a setter:

```
public int Artikelid { get; } // Bad
```

or it isn't public:

```
protected int Artikelid { get; set; } // Bad
```

or it isn't a property at all but it is a field:

```
public int Artikelid; // Bad
```

In all those cases the default model binder wan't be able to set its value from the request. So make sure that this property is declared with public getter and setter on your view model:

```
public int Artikelid { get; set; } // Good
```

Also to avoid possible conflicts try renaming your action parameter:

```
public ActionResult Kortingartikel(IEnumerable<Kortingartikel> model)
```

Comment: See updated code. It is a generated dbml which doesn't look like it has a setter. It didn't have a setter because while debugging I changed it to read only, still doesn't work though

Comment: @jao, yeap. You should never pass your domain entities to your views anyway. You should define view models and only pass and take view models from your views. Autogenerated classes have nothing to do in an ASP.NET MVC application. You could use them in your service or whatever backend layer. In ASP.NET MVC you should work with view models. Sorry but how do you expect the default model binder to be able to assign a value to a property that doesn't even have a setter?

Comment: I also updated the action parameter but that still doesn't work.

Comment: @jao, did you define a setter? Does you property look like this: `public int Artikelid { get; set; }`? If not this won't work.

Comment: yes it has a setter now since I removed the ReadOnly attribute

Comment: @jao, can you try to debug to see if this setter is called? But what I would recommend is to work with view models. It's just horrible to pass such domain model to your views.

Comment: I have now used a view model and that works, but it is kind of repetetive to copy all property values from the viewmodel object to the database object

Comment: It seems that the error was caused by a Bind(exclude) on the model:

Commenting `[Bind(Exclude = "Artikelid")]` did solve the problem, the Artikelid property is now being set.